# Win10 20H2 - inconsistent SMB1 access

Tags: smb

I know Win10 update 2004 broke smb1 access and a subsequent hotfix (or was it 20H2?) fixed it. But in the past week I've had all kinds of problems accessing a single smb1 share located on an old Ws2003 server (to be decommissioned in december, hopefully) from Win10 clients.

Namely: some clients have no issues, some can access only via fqdn, others only via ip. Others yet can't access it at all. After a restart it will work for a while and then randomly stop. Clients that worked only via FQDN will work only via ip the next day and so on. It's been nothing but inconsistent for a couple of weeks now. Any solution?
Win7 clients (we still have a few) does not seem to be affected.

Comment: What errors do the clients receive when trying to connect, if any at all? Do you see anything different between working and not-working clients in a packet capture?

Comment: Enable (and disable) SMBv1 is well documented in this Microsoft article.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

Comment: "I know Win10 update 2004 broke smb1 access and a subsequent hotfix" - Which hotfix so i can do research on the hotfix itself

Comment: (1) Are the clients mapping the network share to a drive-letter? (2) Does restarting the Workstation Service help to restore connection?

Comment: To answer your questions:
- Clients error: explorer will freeze for some minutes, then will throw out an error that the network share cannot be reached.  
- smb/CIF component is enabled on all Win10 boxes. Disabling and reenabling smb1 produces no effect.
- I believe it wasn't a hotfix but the 20H2 update that restored smb access.
- Yes, the network share is mapped to a drive letter via GPO. Restarting will sometimes restore connection for a while and sometimes (most of the times) not.

Comment: I have an older device that does this, and usually a refresh of the listing prior to browsing the shares wakes it up. In my case it seems to be some sort of cache problem where the computer name is listed from a previous use but points to {something invalid}. IP is static too. Win 10 client win 7 device